# how to pass error class object as a result in API?

Tags: api

I have create One API controller and i want to pass custom error class object as a response.

Can any one help me for that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one class for to store error information as shown below.

```
ErrorInformation objError = new ErrorInformation();

try
 {
    test(ref Token, ref SessionToken);
 }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    objError.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    objError.StatusCode = Convert.ToInt16(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
    objError.ErrorType = ex.GetType().ToString();
    objError.ErrorCode = "E01";

    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse<ErrorInformation>(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, objError));
}
```

This will return whole object as result.

```
{
  "StatusCode": 417,
  "ErrorMessage": "Error Detail",
  "ErrorType": "System.DivideByZeroException",
  "ErrorCode": "E01"
}
```

Comment: Yes its working Fine...

Comment: am glad to help